# Can I use multiple fill patterns in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I've created a dodged bar chart in ggplot2 with geom_col(). The code looks like this:

```
cat <- c("A", "A", "A", "A","B", "B", "B", "B")
var <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "T", "X", "Y", "Z", "T")
val <- c(35, 25, 20, 20, 40, 10, 15, 35)
df <- data.frame(var, cat, val)
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = var, y = val, fill = cat), position = "dodge")
```

This produces the following plot:
[image]

I would like each variable to have a different filling colour, for example T = Green, X = Blue etc. and still keep a colour separation between the categories, for example T-A = darkgreen, T-B = lightgreen, X-A = darkblue, X-B = lightblue etc.

Is there an easy way to add this feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do what you're asking is to use the alpha scale:

```r
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = var, y = val, fill = var, alpha = cat), 
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1), guide = guide_none()) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

If you really want to use a grid in the background and don't want to see lines through the pale bars, make sure you plot some white bars of the same dimension underneath:

```r
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = var, y = val, group = cat), 
           position = "dodge", fill = "white", alpha = 1) +
    geom_col(aes(x = var, y = val, fill = var, alpha = cat), 
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1), guide = guide_none())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a superb solution. Is it possible to have the legend at the side with A and B as categories instead of T, X, Y and Z?

Comment: @Pongo yes, but they would be a single pair of light:dark colors, to match the alpha aesthetic. I don't think this would work very well on a legend. What color would you want them to be?

Comment: that doesn't matter. I just want A and B as Categories in the legend instead of T,X,Y and Z.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
cat <- c("A", "A", "A", "A","B", "B", "B", "B")
var <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "T", "X", "Y", "Z", "T")
val <- c(35, 25, 20, 20, 40, 10, 15, 35)
df <- data.frame(var, cat, val)
#Plot
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = var, y = val, fill = interaction(var,cat)), position = "dodge")+
  labs(fill='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

You can customize colors with `scale_fill_*()`. Here an example using a fill scale from `ggsci` package:

```
#Plot 2
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = var, y = val, fill = interaction(var,cat)), position = "dodge")+
  labs(fill='Var')+
  ggsci::scale_fill_futurama()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot and for the quick reply.

Comment: @Pongo Always a pleasure!